# Bootstrap resize responsive offset issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

### [image][image: [![][1]]][image: []]Offsets are not working when resizing browser...

The elements are not centering how they shuld when I resize the browser...the form is stacking horzinotal and the items are floating left and not centering how they must be in not resized browser

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" style="margin-top:8%">
            <h2 class="text-center">Log In To Your Account</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div  class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div role="form" id="loginForm">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="logLogin"><h4>Login</h4></label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Login Here..." id="logLogin" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="logPass"><h4>Password</h4></label>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password Here..." id="logPass" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" value="Log In" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" id="loginSubmit"> 
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <mdall>
                <h4 class="text-center"><strong>...0r Join Us With</strong></h4>
            </mdall>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">      
            <ul class="list-inline">
                <li><a href="facebook.com"><span class="fa fa-facebook-official " aria-hidden="true"></span> Facebook</a></li>
                <li><a href="twitter.com"><span class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></span> Twitter</a></li>
                <li><a href="youtube.com"><span class="fa fa-youtube " aria-hidden="true"></span> Youtube</a></li>
                <li><a href="instagram.com"><span class="fa fa-instagram " aria-hidden="true"></span> Instagram</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add an image? Also, instead of `<div role="form" id="loginForm">` try `<form id="loginForm">` I believe bootstrap targets the `form` element directly when styling forms.

Comment: You have col-md-6 and col-md-offset-3. Are you sure you dont' want them to be col-xs-6 and col-xs-offset-3?

Comment: So are you talking about the text `login`, `password`, and `login button`  aren't being centered?

Comment: Login button and if you look closely at the bottom you will see links down there the are floating left too and it seems to me they are not responsive or something like that...

Comment: Any solutions?????